# Problem with Simple Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

I'm seeing this box in the "Edit Post" page, using the [Simple Facebook Connect plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) 0.25 and WordPress 3.0.4:

> If you can see this, then there is
>   some form of problem showing you the
>   Facebook publishing buttons...

All other Facebook-related plugins are disabled. How can I debug this?

Posted [an issue](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-simple-facebook-connect-if-you-can-see-this-then-there-is-some-form-of-problem?replies=1#post-1923072).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "http://" in the Facebook URL (See the issue for more details).